# Sorting jqgrid datetime column

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am not able to sort on "Last Update" (datetime) column based on jqgrid. Below is my function details. I am new to jqgrid and could not modify the library. Any suggestion based on below code:

```
 public function get_json_colModel()
{
    $column_lables = array("Location", "Customer","Cust ID", "Updated By", "Last Update", "Comment");
    $get_formoption = function(&$value, $column_name) {
        $value = array("label" => $column_name."<span class='text-danger'>*</span>");
    };
    $get_searchoptions = function(&$value,$column_name) {
        $value = array("dataUrl"=>"dropdown/testdata/search/".strtolower($column_name));
    };
    $get_editoption = function(&$value, $column_name){
        if($column_name == null)
            $value = null;
        $value = array("dataUrl"=>"dropdown/testdata/add_edit/".strtolower($column_name));
    };
    $columns =  array("Location", "Customer","Cust ID",updated By", "Last Update", "Comment");
    $searchoptions= array("Location"=> "", "Customer" => "");
    array_walk($searchoptions, $get_searchoptions);
    $editoptions = array("Location" => "", "Customer" => "");
    array_walk($editoptions, $get_editoption);
    $hidden = array("_Customer_ID" => true, "_UNIQUE_ID" => true);

    $col_val_map = array(
        "name" => $columns,
        "label" => $column_lables,
        "width" => $width,
        "editable" => array(true,true,false,true),
        "search" => array(true,true,true,true,true,true),
        "searchoptions" => $searchoptions,
        "sortable" => array(true,true,true,false,true,false),
        "editoptions" => $editoptions,
        "editrules" => $editrules,
        "hidden" => $hidden,
        );
    $testdata = $this->getGrid($col_val_map, $columns);
    return json_encode($testdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code instead of the library. The problem you have is that your column names contain spaces. The name should NOT contain spaces.

```
 $columns =  array("Location", "Customer","Cust ID",updated By", "Last Update", "Comment");
```

Modify your code so that there is no space in the column names.

If you are new, then it will be a good idea to read some documentation -  but this depend on the version of jqGrid used.

Comment: Actual names doesn't have any spaces, these are jut UI specific names.